# Caching hashed password in encrypted cookie for connecting to legacy API?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, session, session-cookies, legacy

I am building a ASP.NET Core application. The client has an old ASP.NET application that exposes an API for authentication. It asks for a username and a MD5 hashed password (don't ask me why it works this way). Unfortunately, I do not get back any type of authorization token in the response. All it returns is some info about the user and a success or failure flag. My app needs to authenticate any request. My app will be pretty small and will only have a few API endpoints. Basically it involves opening a form, filling it out, and then uploading it to a folder on the server. That's it.

I need to be able to create some type of session so that users don't have to keep typing their username and password over and over again. They may open several of these forms on the same day. I also need some way to reauthenticate with the legacy API on each request.

I know that the right solution here would be to create some type of SSO login system that both the legacy app and my app would use. But unfortunately we're working under a tight deadline and won't have time to implement and test it. We may work on it for Phase 2 of the project later on.

One option I thought about was caching the MD5 hashed password in the encrypted ASP.NET Core Identity cookie. That way, on each request, I can retrieve the cached password from the session cookie and reauthenticate with the legacy API. I've read many posts on here about how it's always a bad idea to store the password in a cookie even if it is encrypted.

Another option is to cache the password using ASP.NET Core Session State or something similar so that the password at least never leaves the server. The problem with this though is that if the app has to be restarted, I believe this cache would get deleted and cause the user to have to login again.

Another option I thought of: Maybe I don't need to reauthenticate with the legacy API every time and therefore don't need to cache any passwords in the first place? The client specified that my app should automatically log out the user if there is no activity for 10 minutes. So maybe my app only goes to the legacy API once at the beginning and after that maintains its own session separate from the legacy app? This doesn't seem like a good solution either though as it means a user could be authorized for my app while not being authorized for the legacy app (if their password changed or account got deleted for example).

Is there a solution I'm not thinking of here?

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question. I ended up talking to the client about this issue and they seem to not be too concerned about it even after letting them know the risks of caching a password using one of the above methods or a similar method. I let them know this is a bad practice and should use access tokens instead. After a certain point, if they don't care then there isn't much I can do. They did seem to be open to changing things later though but like I said, we're on a tight deadline for the 1st phase of this project.

For anyone else facing this issue, the important thing is to talk to the stakeholders of your app to make sure they understand what the risks are.